# method does not return the latest record

Tags: boto

In the following example I can return the record if I already know it's sequence number that was returned when I inserted the data.
But how do I return all the data that has been added by different devices?

```
import boto
mykin = boto.connect_kinesis(aws_access_key_id='access_key',
                             aws_secret_access_key='secret_key')
myput = mykin.put_record(stream_name='mytest', data='abcdefghij',
                         partition_key='parti11', b64_encode=True)
myiterator = mykin.get_shard_iterator(stream_name='mytest',
                                      shard_id='shardId-000000000000',
                                      shard_iterator_type='AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER',
                                      starting_sequence_number=
                                        myput['SequenceNumber'])
mykin.get_records(shard_iterator=myiterator['ShardIterator'])
```

Answer (score 1):

in your producer:

```
kinesis = boto.kinesis.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
response = kinesis.describe_stream('stream_name')
shard_id = response['StreamDescription']['Shards'][0]['ShardId']
response = kinesis.get_shard_iterator('stream_name', shard_id, 'TRIM_HORIZON')
```